# How do I create a list from A to Z in F#

Tags: regex, list, f#

In F# you can create a list from 1 to 10 using the range operator, but is it possible to use letters from the alphabet to do the same? I have been searching for a while and trying a few different things but with no success, and I don't want to have to type the alphabet in the program manually.

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
let list = [ "a" .. "z" ]
```

I know I would have to use regex somehow but I can't find a lot of information on it and it seems to be called something different in F#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to use single quotes to specify characters rather than strings:

```
let list = [ 'a' .. 'z' ]

// yields: [a; b; c; ... ]
```

Comment: And if you do want them to be strings, you can simply do a `List.map` after you've created the `chars`:  `let letters = ['a'..'z'] |> List.map string`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know single quotes were just for characters. Thanks, Aaron also.